# Limit HTML date input to today's date

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input type date on my form that I limited to only use today's date by setting the min and max attribute to today with the help of javascript. The problem is the user can still type a different date instead of picking it using the little calendar popup. Is there a way to not allow this?

Comment: How about the `readonly` property if you don't want it to be changed?

Comment: why do you have an input that cannot be entered? that looks to me like a label/plain text...

Comment: Don't use an input then...

Comment: Share the code.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, yeah it shouldn't be a datepicker but the users didn't know what they wanted until several code refactoring. But they also don't have/need to fill every row in the form as they are doing some lab analisis for specific entries. We also don't know how many rows the tables are gonna get nor which row is going to be filled.

Answer (score 0):

According to specification `min` and `max` shall only affect form submission if violated. GUI behavior is not standardized and therefore does depend on the browser vendor and its specific version. For example, on `Chrome 97` I'm not allowed to type the year 2019 in this [demo page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date). As you can see the year text is gray and I'm not allowed to alter it:

[image]

You should use a non-native element, to achieve consistent behavior. See for example [JQuery DatePicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: I wonder how min/max deals with different timezones.

Comment: I would guess they both use the local time zone. Or do you wonder how they behave during timezone change? Well, that is a rabbit hole I would advise staying away from ;)

Comment: So if the user tries to use a different date it shouldn't be able to submit the form? That's weird I'm not getting any error and the form is submited with the date travelling into the server.

Comment: Yes, if you use a plain `form` with a `submit` button, the form should not submit. Have you tested with other browsers? Or perhaps you are using something else to submit, like jQuery?

Comment: Oh yes I'm using the onclick event that calls for a javascript function which verifies the user credentials in the server and then submits the form.

Comment: Nop, `onclick` will still trigger. Use [onsubmit](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onsubmit.asp)